# .htaccess rule to NGINX

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following .httaccess rule which changes path to logo depending on host. If host ".ru" it takes from /img/up/ru/b-logo instead of /img/up/b-logo

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/img/up/)(b-logo)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  %1ru/%2%3 [L]
```

Can anybody help me rewrite it for nginx?
Rules from different converters do not work

Comment: It depends on how you structure your `server` blocks. If you have one `server` block for many host names, you will need to use an `if` statement. If `example.ru` is handled by its own `server` block, a `location` statement can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
map $http_host$uri $lng {
    default $uri;
    ~^example\.ru/img/up/b-logo(.*) /img/up/ru/b-logo$1;
}

server
    server_name example.com example.ru;
    ...
    location /img/up/b-logo {
        rewrite .* $lng$is_args$args;
    }
    ...
}
```

nginx location selection algorithm is quite complex ([description in russian language](https://habr.com/post/348206/)), make sure that this `location` block will take priority against other defined locations.